# Is there any CLI multiboot ISO USB creater in Linux?

Tags: live-usb, multiboot

I use `multisystem` as multiboot ISO USB creater in my Ubuntu. I don't know whether it has any CLI interface.

I find this CLI tool because most of the CLI tool is more powerful than GUI one. And when I use a CLI tool I can learn the command and the inner mechanism relative to GUI.

Mention any CLI tool that have more functionality including multiboot ISO USB creation.

Comment: I don't know of such tool but wanted to point out that you're relying on a false misconception.  There is absolutely no reason that a CLI tool would be more powerful than a properly designed GUI program.

Answer (score 1):

[MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/) supports CLI for iso installation, uninstallation and many features for multiboot.